# Sails, Sockets, and Authorization

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, authorization, sails.js

I want to build a chat like whatsapp. 
(Each user has a contact list which he can speak only with them)
My server auth is based on facebook tokens.
And I would like my sockets auth to be the same.

The current scenario :
-- after the user logged in, the front end sends a socket connection request to my sails server.
-- In the server "beforeConnect" function, I find the user by his fb token.
-- the user is found , the socket is connected successfully.

The problem : I need the user details to be available on the socket, That's because I want to find his chats, and to update him about only his chats and new messages.

That's how my beforeConnect function looks like now.
[image]

P.S: Don't know if it's worth mentioning, but I'm using socket.io in the client side, and not the sails.io.js I saw in the documents to connect my sails Server sockets.

Comment: A bit late but... you need user details in the controllers? From what I've gathered so far, you can either user `req.socket.getId()` and then along with session data associate it to a user. From what I read, it seems a better approach is to use a policy as in http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/05/json-web-tokens-examples/ (look for api/policies/tokenAuth.js). This could be expensive though if you authenticate against FB each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onConnect method is deprecated for newer version, you can do authorization with token on connect event , you have to store token while connect and check on other listener for authentication, put this code in config/bootstrap.js

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) { 

    // handle connect socket first event executes after logged in
    sails.io.on('connect', function (socket){
        // store facebook token here
    });

    // handle custom listener for other stuff
    sails.io.on('doSomeStuff', function (socket){
        // check facebook token match with requested token
    });
cb();
};
```

client :
you can simple emit "doSomeStuff" after logged in with facebook and pass token with each request

Comment: Thank you very much !   -  Currently I do authorization on each request, like if the user tries to connect - I process his fb token and let him connect.    even if the socket is connected, with each request I send the fb token, find the user , and then continue to controller.  It's okay to process the fb token every time?

Comment: hello @TalGvili, for authentication user following post give you more information about how to manage token

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548009/user-authentication-using-socket-io)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548009/user-authentication-using-socket-io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548009/user-authentication-using-socket-io)